# Jquery Rest Service response works only for Chrome browser but not in IE or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

When visiting the site http://www.dentalo.se you should see this image.

[image]

I'm a calling a RestService at http://www.dentalo.se/RestService/Dentalo.svc/Companies and I know it working and getting a response. I have tested the service.

I'm using Google Maps to render location for the Google maps.
It renders location when using **Chrome** browser. But I cannot understand why it doesn't work in **Firefox, Internet Explorer**. On mobile devices it doesn't work on any browser even **chrome**.

This is the error message I receive in Firefox. If just visit http://www.dentalo.se you will see the error. I only want to add the relevant code. If you need more code tell me.

---

> sg = [object Object], url = error, line = [Exception... "Failure" 
>   nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   http://dentalo.se/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js :: .send :: line
>   6"  data: no]

---

This some **JavaScript** code that I have included.

```
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Start Google Map JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=sv"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/gmaps/gmaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End Google Map JavaScript -->
```

shorter version of **JavaScript** Code

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ShowPosition);
            }
            else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
            function showError(error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                        break;
                }
            }
            function ShowPosition(position) {
                //begin rest call
                $("#latitude").val(position.coords.latitude);
                $("#longitude").val(position.coords.longitude);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    url: "http://www.dentalo.se/RestService/Dentalo.svc/Companies",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        map = new GMaps({
                            el: '#map',
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude,
                            zoom: 15,
                            zoomControl: true,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            zoomControlOpt: {
                                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                            },
                            panControl: true,
                            scrollwheel: true
                        });
                        map.addMarker({
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude,
                            title: 'Min position',
                            icon: 'http://www.dentalo.se/assets/img/map/user_x64.png'
                        });
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                                    map.addMarker({
                                                    lat: item.Latitude ,
                                                    lng: item.Longitude ,
                                                    title: item.Address ,
                                                    icon: GetMarkerImage(item.Status),
                                                    infoWindow: { 
                                                        content: '<div style="width: 300px"><h4>' + item.Name + '</h4><br /><p>' + item.Address + ', ' + item.County.Name + '</p><div class="four columns alpha"><a class="btn blue ' + SetDisplayClass(item.Status) + '" href="booking/' + item.CompanyId + '" ><i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i> Boka</a> <a href="#" onClick="showPopUp(&apos;' + item.CompanyId +'&apos;);return false;" class="btn default">Information</a></div></div>',
                                                    }
                                        })
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (msg, url, line) {
                        //alert('error trapped in error: function(msg, url, line)');
                        alert('msg = ' + msg + ', url = ' + url + ', line = ' + line);
                    }
                });
```

Many thanks.

*** Begin Edit ***

I have solved the problem.
It was a Url issue. In the ajax call to the rest service you should not specify the complete Url.

You should do it like this

I change this line

url: "http://www.dentalo.se/RestService/Dentalo.svc/Companies",

To

url: "RestService/Dentalo.svc/Companies",

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: "RestService/Dentalo.svc/Companies",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                map = new GMaps({
                    el: '#map',
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude,
                    zoom: 15,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoomControlOpt: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                    },
                    panControl: true,
                    scrollwheel: true
                });
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude,
                    title: 'Min position',
                    icon: 'http://www.dentalo.se/assets/img/map/user_x64.png'
                });
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            map.addMarker({
                                            lat: item.Latitude ,
                                            lng: item.Longitude ,
                                            title: item.Address ,
                                            icon: GetMarkerImage(item.Status),
                                            infoWindow: { 
                                                content: '<div style="width: 300px"><h4>' + item.Name + '</h4><br /><p>' + item.Address + ', ' + item.County.Name + '</p><div class="four columns alpha"><a class="btn blue ' + SetDisplayClass(item.Status) + '" href="booking/' + item.CompanyId + '" ><i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i> Boka</a> <a href="#" onClick="showPopUp(&apos;' + item.CompanyId +'&apos;);return false;" class="btn default">Information</a></div></div>',
                                            }
                                })
                });
            },
            error: function (msg, url, line) {
                //alert('error trapped in error: function(msg, url, line)');
                alert('msg = ' + msg + ', url = ' + url + ', line = ' + line);
            }
        });
```

*** End Edit ***

Comment: Error messages, more details, etc.

Comment: I have edit my question with error message

Comment: The only error that I'm getting it's a timeout, could you please check the timeout of your request

Answer (score 0):

the `getCurrentPosition` method has an infinite time out by default. Try this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ShowPosition, showError, {timeout:2000})
```

There are two other options you can set in this object: `enableHighAccuracy` and `maximumAge`

Check out: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html for more info.

Comment: I don't think thats the issue. could it be I am using wrong jquery version for ex ff? Why is it complaining about  http://dentalo.se/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js line 6?

Comment: No, geolocation is HTML5 and does not depend on jQuery.  It could be your browser version.  Currently you are not using your error callback, try it with the second parameter and see what that results in.  BTW, I can get my location at the url you provided with IE 11 but I have not tried in FF.  My guess is that FF is complaining about something related to rendering the map.

Comment: I think it is some rest issue because I have error handler function on error restcal that is throwing the alert


**error: function (msg, url, line) {
    //alert('error trapped in error: function(msg, url, line)');
    alert('msg = ' + msg + ', url = ' + url + ', line = ' + line);
}**

But I am really stuck here.